# Type Error: string from deserializer instead of int when load csv to table

Tags: csv, hive

I'm Cherry. I want to load `csv` to the table.

```
add jar /home/hadoop/csv-serde.jar;
create database IF NOT EXISTS test;
use test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.neighbors(
    objID bigint ,
    NeighborObjID bigint ,
    distance float ,
    type smallint ,
    neighborType smallint ,
    mode tinyint ,
    neighborMode tinyint) row format serde  'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde';
```

But describe neighbors:

```
objid   string  from deserializer
neighborobjid   string  from deserializer
distance    string  from deserializer
type    string  from deserializer
neighbortype    string  from deserializer
mode    string  from deserializer
neighbormode    string  from deserializer
```

All attributes become "string   from deserializer" instead of int or float.

```
        objID bigint ,
        NeighborObjID bigint ,
        distance float ,
        type smallint ,
        neighborType smallint ,
        mode tinyint ,
        neighborMode tinyint
```

This is what I want. I want to load `csv` to neighbors.

Comment: you are using CSV-Serde. so you may end with 'string from deserializer'  which does Ser-Dser ... instead use format delimited by ','

Answer (score 2):

**use**

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED Fields terminated by ','
STORED as textfile;

**insted of**

row format serde  'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'